# Что такое чейн SSL сертификата

Tags: ssl

Собственно, что такое чейн SSL сертификата? Ничего нагуглить не удалось. И собственно, как можно очистить чейн?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: То есть, это промежуточные центры сертификации, я верно понял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

технически [x.509-сертификат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0_X.509) — это файл, содержащий публичный ключ (и ещё некоторую служебную информацию) и подпись издателя (ею подписывается и ключ и служебная информация).

проверить подпись издателя можно с помощью **его** публичного ключа, который содержится в **его** сертификате. который также содержит и подпись вышестоящего в цепочке издателя.

и так рекурсивно до «самого главного» издателя, иначе говоря — корневого [центра сертификации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

такая цепочка связанных подписями сертификатов называется «[цепочкой доверия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)». («чейн» — это, вероятно, транслитерация английского слова «цепочка» — «chain»)

обычно сертификаты распространяются в простом текстовом файле, содержащем закодированный алгоритмом [base64](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) собственно сертификат, между двух строк:

```
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----
```

и

```
----- END CERTIFICATE -----
```

а упомянутую выше цепочку сертификатов нередко распространяют не в виде набора файлов такого формата, а в виде одного, в котором последовательно записано содержимое этих файлов:

```
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----
base64 одного сертификата
----- END CERTIFICATE -----
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----
base64 другого сертификата
----- END CERTIFICATE -----
...
```

возможно, под фразой «очистить чейн» подразумевается «оставить только один сертификат» (вероятно, самый последний из выпущенных, так сказать, «конечный»). уточните у того, от кого услышали эту фразу.

если это так, то «сборный» файл надо разбить на отдельные файлы, и с помощью, например, программы openssl, выяснить, какой из них вам нужен (это будет не обязательно самый последний по порядку — ведь ничто не мешает записать в исходный файл сертификаты в произвольном порядке).